# Adding every other integer from 0 to n (recursive func)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, integer

The function I am writing is meant to add every other integer from `0` to `n`. For example, if you inputted `6`, you would get `12` because `6 + 4 + 2 + 0 = 12`.

I was working with a list at first but realized I have to be working with integers instead. Below is my attempt, but I get `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`.

I'm confused as to how to fix this problem and make it a proper recursive function.

```
def addNum(n):

    if len(n) == 0:
        return 0 
    else:
        return n[0] + addNum(n[::2])

print(addNum(6)) #example of how you would call the function
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to add just the alternating integers, it should be like

```
def addNum(n):
    if n < 1 :
        return 0 
    else:
        return n + addNum(n-2)
print(addNum(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass an `Integer` to your function `addnum`, but you need a list. So you have to write `addnum([6])` to create a list with the `6` as a single entry.

You have to call the function with the argument, reduced by 2 if you want to work without a list.

```
def addnum(n):
    if n == 0:
      return 0
    else:
      return n + addnum(n - 2)

print(addnum(6))
```

This gives the output `12`.

Comment: I think I'm aiming for it to work with integers rather than lists (which is what I initially thought I needed, but misread). When I switch it to a list it gives me a maximum recursion depth error.

Answer (score -1):

so first of all the func len() is for lengths and you actually don't need that, what you need is a list comprehension. I assume that you don't know them so go and learn about them because they can help with these kinds of functions because they aren't that hard to write and are highly flexible.

**The code below here does exactly what you want!**

```
def addnum(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return sum([list for list in range(0,n+1,2)])
print(addnum(10))
```

1. first I create a function named addnum which has one parameter called n.
2. secondly I created the if else clauses, if the number is equal to 0 it returns 0. Else it returns the sum of every odd integer from 0 the the range. n+1 is here just to get the number you put in because the func range doesn't include the last value.

Comment: Sorry but why the down vote? the code does what the guy wanted it to do. more complex but it does.